# Illegal Character in static field of R.java. How to remove this?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I have tried cleaning the project but no success. I even tried opening R.java file in notepad and removing this illegal character line. But it reappeared while restarting the Android Studio.

public static final int venue_name_MSB`=0x7f080150;

[image]

Comment: R.java is an auto-generated file which contains references to all the resources you create,  so it cannot be edited, because with each build it is auto-generated.
You should try to remove the illegal character from your resource where you have set it and then clean and try to build again, it should work

Comment: Those variables are generated from your project i think, this illegal character is on one of your xml you've created

Comment: Where else have you defined `venue_name_MSB`? Do a Find All with `ctrl + shift + F`

Comment: I have removed the resource id but still error is not going.

Comment: In which case try cleaning your project (`Build > Clean Project`) and rebuild

Comment: Now when I ctrl+click this declaration, there is no reference showing in Android studio

Comment: check ids in your layout files

Comment: i have removed the ids from layout file. now when i ctrl click the errored reference, there is no usage found showing

Comment: Sorted out with the help of Android Lint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds to me a charset issue. 
go to

> Settings > Editor > File Encodings

and set `Global Encoding` and `Project Encoding` to UTF-8

then clean and rebuild the project.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your project to another location in your hard disk and then restart android studio.  Then do a clean, and then a rebuild.

It should fix your problem.